# Mixed mode applications initialize error

Tags: .net, c++-cli

First I would like to thanks to all programmers.

My problem is very confusing.

I have Windows XP SP3 and .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on my system.

When I compile my C++/CLI source code with /clr:safe option, produced executable assembly does work well, I mean run well but when I mix some native C++ and managed C++ code together and compile the source code with /clr or /clr:pure mode, the generated assembly works well for a while and then after a while the following message comes out when I again try to run the executable assembly "The application failed to initialize properly, 0xc000007b. Please click OK to terminate the application."

Note: This error message only comes out when I compile the code with /clr or /clr:pure modes and mix the native and managed code.
I have checked and cleaned my system from viruses but this problem could not be solved.
Could you please help me to find out the real problem?

Thanks for advance...

---

Yes Visual C++ Redistributable version 2008 is installed on my x86 Windows-XP 32bit machine! I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express SP1 as my development tool. Some tools that come with VC++ 2008 Express SP1 also do not run and give the same error. I also noticed that this error only pops up when I build Mixed Mode or Pure Mode C++/CLI executable assembly, not when I build a DLL assembly that I later consume from a safe C#, Visual Basic or C++/CLI executable file.

Comment: It is not a good match with the description, but this error is almost always caused by trying to run 32-bit code on a 64-bit operating system in a 64-bit process.  If the EXE project is written in C# or VB.NET then be sure to set the Platform target to x86.

Comment: I merged your account with the cookie-based one; so you should be able to edit the question now.

Answer (score 0):

> I have Windows XP SP3 and .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on my system.

Did you also install the Visual C++ Redistributable Runtime matching your version of Visual Studio?